# TypeInitializationException when starting application from fileshare

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-7-x64

When I start the application locally everything works fine but as soon as I copy it to a fileshare I get the following exception:

```
Anwendung: WWW.exe
Frameworkversion: v4.0.30319
Beschreibung: Der Prozess wurde aufgrund einer unbehandelten Ausnahme beendet.
Ausnahmeinformationen: System.TypeInitializationException
Stapel:
   bei WWW.exe.Client.App.Application_Startup(System.Object, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
   bei System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   bei MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   bei MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   bei System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   bei System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   bei System.Windows.Application.Run()
   bei WWW.exe.Client.App.Main()
```

Any hints what could to wrong here?

EDIT:
I have wrapped my whole method into a try catch block, but the crash happens before the first line is hit.

```
 void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Application_Startup_Internal(sender, e);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Tracer.Write(exception); // writes the exception to the event log.
                throw;
            }
        }
```

EDIT 2:
I tried the idea mentioned in this blogpost: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e05d960-9bba-496b-bf42-9608b94f3c10/debugdiagnostics-intialization-failed-after-installing-security-patch-kb2840628 
and this solved my problem. But it means I have to remove all my diagnostics, which I can't do of course.

Comment: Is it your application? If so, can you debug it or add logging code to see the details of the exception and add them to the question?

Comment: It is my application but it's only happening on my test machines. I have found out that it might be related to the update KB2840628. I can't attach to any unhandeled exceptions because the exception occurs before any of my code runs.

Comment: `Application_Startup` seems to be your code. Place a try-catch block with some logging there. Alternatively handle the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event (attach a handler in `Main`).

Comment: I can't see an edit of the question. Do you mean you edited your comment? If yes, my comment was already based on that text (`Main` is your code).

Comment: Sorry, too many open windows, I have added the edit now. This is a WPF application, the Main() method gets automatically created.

Comment: You can create a custom `Main` method and select it as startup method in the project properties.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34231/discussion-between-florian-gerhardt-and-cremor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of a bad optimization in the update for .NET 4.0 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840628/en-us.
As described in the article it can be fixed by installing the update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872041/en-us.